# How to convert the hex value in C?

Tags: c, hex

How do I perform the following hex conversions:

- Converting the value `10` as hex to `A`
- Converting the value `11` to `B`
- Converting the value `12` to `C`
- Converting the value `13` to `D`
- Converting the value `14` to `E`
- Converting the value `15` to `F`

Comment: `printf("%x\n", value);`?

Comment: but the value is already hex, for example hex value 11, how to convert it to B?

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. Also see [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: @user2131316: If `11` is already in hex, then its value in hex is `11`, not `B`...

Comment: @JanHudec I tried the same as printf("%x\n", value);, but it still shows 11

Comment: If it already *is* hex, then you "convert" it by subtracting `6`.

Comment: @user2131316: If the value is `11` _hex_, it is not `B` under any sensible or less sensible interpretation.

Comment: It's a [BCD value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). Convert to decimal using `dec = 10*(value >> 4)+(value & 0x0f)` (sanity checks omitted for clarity), then treat as a regular decimal-to-hex by printing with `%X`.

Answer (score 4):

The number 11<sub>16</sub>, in hex, is equivalent to 17<sub>10</sub> decimal. You can't "convert" it to b<sub>16</sub>, since that is 11<sub>10</sub> decimal which is not the same.

It's very unclear what you're trying to accomplish.

If you do this:

```
const int seventeen = 0x11; /* Hexadecimal integer literal. */
```

or this:

```
const int seventeen = 17; /* Decimal integer literal, with the same value. */
```

Then that is not the same as doing:

```
const int eleven = 0xb;
```

or this:

```
const int eleven = 11;
```

The values, the bits that become set in the memory allocated to the variable, are *different*:

```
if(seventeen != eleven)
   printf("they're not the same!\n");
```

So the above *will* print "they're not the same!".

Comment: I am trying to ask is: if you have the hex value of 0x11, how can we compose it as B, and if it is 0x12, how to compose it as C?

Comment: @user2131316 You can't! `0x11 != 0xb`. It's as simple as that.

Comment: 0x11 is not B, 11 (base 10) is B, 0x11 is 17 (base 10). Are you trying to parse strings that contain hexadecimal representation of numbers?

Comment: no, I have the hex value int i = 0x11; how to compose it as 0xB?
or if it is 0x12, how to compose it as 0xC?

Comment: @user2131316: "Subtract 6" is the only sane answer at this point, and even that doesn't make any sense in general.

Comment: @user2131316: The "0x" before a number means that it is hexadecimal. So 0x11(hexa)== 17(decimal)!!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print a decimal number as hexadecimal, use the `"%x"` format code:

```
int value = 11;
printf("Value is %d decimal, %x hexadecimal\n", value, value);
```

---

If you want to go from `0x11` to `0xb`, then the only way to do it is to subtract `6`:

```
int value = 0x11;
printf("Before: Value = %d, or 0x%02x\n", value, value);

value -= 6;
printf("After : Value = %d, or 0x%02x\n", value, value);
```

The above will print

```
Before: Value = 17, or 0x11
After : Value = 11, or 0x0b
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any conversion to display the hexadecimal representation of `int`:

```
int value = 11;
printf("0x%X", value);
```

outputs `0xB`. Just like:

```
int value = 0xB;
printf("%d", value);
```

outputs `11` since 11<sub>10</sub> = B<sub>16</sub> ~> 0xB

You also wrote that you have hexadecimal value `11` and you want to convert it to `B` (that's actually converting decimal value 11 to hex value 0xB). But in case that `11` was hexadecimal value already (`0x11`), i.e. 11<sub>16</sub> ~> it's decimal value would be 1 x 16<sup>1</sup> + 1 x 16<sup>0</sup> = 16 + 1 = 17.

Answer (score 0):

```
char to_hex(char i)
{
    if(i >= 16 || i < 0) return 0;
    else if(i >= 10) return i - 10 + 'A';
    else return i + '0';
}
```

[sample](http://ideone.com/Ayoh0q)